# Expectation of max(X, Y) where X and Y follow a joint normal distribution with correlation of $\rho$

Tags: expectation, normal-distribution, correlation

As stated in the title, I am looking for the solution to this expectation, possibly as a function of $\rho$.
One relevant solution I find is [Lord Shark the Unknown's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2630764/457380), from which I can derive $E(max(X, Y)) = \frac{1}{2}E(|V|)$. But I am not sure what to do next.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have zero means and unit variances, then you might follow this answer:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382237/expected-value-of-ordered-statistics#382260.

Comment: Actually, in your linked post the OP has answered your question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Indeed! My fault. Thank you.