# Expectation of the maximum of two correlated standard normal variables squared

Tags: expected-value, order-statistics

Assume we have two random variables X and Y. They are joint Gaussian with mean 0 and standard deviation 1 and correlation $\rho$.

1. What is $E[max\{X^2, Y^2\}]$
2. What is $E[max\{X,Y\}^2]$

I know that when X and Y are independent, $P\{max\{X,Y\}<m\} = P\{X<m\}*P\{Y<m\}$. Also $X^2$ is a Chi-square random variable. But I am having trouble to use this equation when X and Y are not independent.

Comment: Let $Z=X-\rho Y$. Show that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. Write $Y$ as $\frac {X-z} {\rho} $. Work with $(X,Z)$.

Comment: For your purpose, it is easier to use the identity $\max\{X^2,Y^2\}=\frac12\left[X^2+Y^2+|X^2-Y^2|\right]=\frac12\left[X^2+Y^2+|X+Y||X-Y|\right]$. If the second one is the square of the maximum, then using a similar approach gives the mean and variance of $\max\{X,Y\}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2630752/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank your for the hint! Can you help me with calculating the $E[|X+Y||X-Y|]$? I know X+Y and X-Y are independent. But is |X+Y| and |X-Y| independent as well? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, they are; (measurable) functions of independent random variables are also independent.